# Haskell - add n number of 0s into a list

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to haskell. Given list [a] of integers and an integer n, how can I add n 0s in the beginning of list [a]. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super straightforward: it's just

```
replicate n 0 ++ list
```

where `replicate` just makes a list of `n` occurrences of the specified element, and `++` combines the lists together.